# Admin required for Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project

Tags: .net, deployment, installation, uac, setup-deployment

I have a VS 2008 Setup Project that is installing a very simple application in the local user's App Folder.  When the Setup Project runs, it is requiring the Admin to login to run it.  How can I allow a Standard User to run the installation.  There are no Prerequisites.  The MSI file is the only file to be run (no Setup.exe).  I have signed the msi with a certificate that is installed on the user's machine as Trusted.  I just can't get rid of the Admin login requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a manifest on the setup.exe that says "please run me asInvoker?" If not, heuristics apply based on the file name. If you rename tetris.exe to setup99.exe it will ask to elevate when you run it.

If you have no manifest, add one - either embedded (VS 2008 should be able to do that for you) or external (just put the manifest in the same folder as the exe.) If you can't or won't do that, rename the exe to something that doesn't include setup, patch, or update in its name. I prefer the manifest myself.

Comment: I only am trying to run MyApp.msi to install the app, not Setup.exe.  I don't know how I would even add a manifest to just the msi file.  I am not using bootstrapping.

Comment: Hm, MSIs are supposed to be happy to run asInvoker. Are you installing for all users?

Comment: I changed the VS 2008 Setup Project to default to "Just Me" and when I try and test this, Just Me is selected.